# ADF, CopyData & Rest API

Tags: json, rest, azure-data-factory

I actually try to make a simple pipeline to read JSON Data on a API REST and store it in a database.

I try first with a CopyData acticity.
I set up the linked service, the dataset, etc etc...

I need to call an API with POST Method and a Body's payload.
Everything is set, I launch the pipeline and... the api respond like i don't providethe Body's payload.

Double check it, check it via the generated json :

[image: ADF: Body request - seems ok]

and in the generated pipeline JSON

```
...
     "source": {
                        "type": "RestSource",
                        "httpRequestTimeout": "00:01:40",
                        "requestInterval": "00.00:00:00.010",
                        "requestMethod": "POST",
                        "requestBody": "{ \"startDate\":\"2022-09-01T00:00\", \"endDate\":\"2022-09-01T23:59\"}"
                    },
...
```

Because **requestBody** wait a string type, the double quote are escaped...
Never wanted to work. Nothing to do. API never seems to find the body.

I find the "Web" activity and I decide to give it a quick try.

Same api call,same linked service, same dataset same url, same method, same body payload...
Just a big copy&paste.

And it's work...
So, why Web activity works and not CopyData?

I reopen the generated pipeline's JSON and :

Web Activity:

```
"body": {
   "startDate": "2022-09-01T00:00",
   "endDate": "2022-09-01T23:59"
},
```

Copy Activity:

```
"requestBody": "{ \"startDate\":\"2022-09-01T00:00\", \"endDate\":\"2022-09-01T23:59\"}"
```

Seems that Web activity don't request the body type to be a String.
Maybe it's the problem,
Maybe Copy rewrite body "badly" and it's fail.

So,
Do I miss something?
or
Is it a bug?

And how do you do it? *(consume API data in adf pipeline)*

Cheers,
Mike.

Comment: hi @Michael Oullion, try to use `@json({ "startDate":"2022-09-01T00:00", "endDate":"2022-09-01T23:59"})` in copy activity body .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1000566/adf-copydata-amp-rest-api.html?childToView=1001129#answer-1001129

Just miss the additional header : content-type : application/json
...
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@json('{"startDate":"2022-09-01T00:00","endDate":"2022-09-01T23:59"}')` in copy activity body

[image: Ref1]

After using the above dynamic content, my copy activity receives the  `requestBody` as an object. Look at the following image:

[image]

Comment: Hi @BhanunagasaiVamsi,
thx for your answer, but unfortunately, i can't do it work.
Everything seems ok with the Dynamic content but at runtime, it's failed :
`Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'requestBody' property to 'System.String' type.`